# Backend "Process moved to a different machine" and fails withh error 500

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a process that takes around five minutes to complete. It runs on a cron job every two hours in a backend instance.

Recently the process has started to fail; not every time but a few times a day. First thing that happens is that the memcache starts to throw exceptions:

```
04:21:13.640 com.google.appengine.api.memcache.LogAndContinueErrorHandler handleServiceError: Service error in memcache
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache get: exception getting 1 key (ItemFollowableCompleted:RegionUS:P8XD:0)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.handleApiProxyException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:68)
at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.absorbParentException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:109)
```

None of these are fatal exceptions but a few seconds later the process terminated without warning or shutdown message. Logs show

```
04:21:30.591 Process moved to a different machine.
```

and an error 500.

Is this a google infrastructure problem related to memcache or is there something in the app code that could be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an error in Google infrastructure. Your process is expected to be moved among instances when needed (maintenance, more demand from your side, ...), and there's nothing you can do to prevent it.

Nonetheless there are a few things you could do to alleviate any effect this could have in your app.

Look [1] for some suggestions on how to keep track of your pending jobs when your instance is shut down and also have a look at the background threads.

I'm guessing you're using Python, if not, look for your corresponding language.

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/#Python_Backend_states

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I use ndb.putmulti() to load data. I tried a few things
1. increase my backends machine size, I moved to B4_1G 
2. sleep between ndb.putmulti() (2 minutes for every 200 entities)
3. Dedicated memcache (1G)

1 and 2 were not very helpful, 3 seems to help.

I think rapid updates to ndb datastore affecting memcache is the root cause in my case. I could not find any other way besides paying for dedicated memcache.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the issue "*Process moved to a different machine*" in the backend module too.

The issue context is as below:

1. Get the query result from one KIND
2. Iterating each entity in the query result, I will do some tasks and write new entities to different KINDs
3. The "Process moved to a different machine" happens during the half of iterating

After some experiments, I found it is due to "**too many writing transactions in one request**". Everything is fine when the size of query result is small, but cause problem when it becomes larger.

The final solution I took is to use `Task Queue`, the work should be done for a entity is looked as one task and be put into the `PushQueue`. So the issue is gone.

Hope this will help :)