# Memcache (InnvocationTargetException) blows up Backend Instance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an appengine module which runs as a background instance (b4, basic scaling) and which iterates over a huge amount of data and processes it.

It runs correctly through when a smaller amount of data is processed, but when data becomes bigger i start to get multiple Exceptions. At the beginning an InvocationTargetException causes a MemcacheServiceException, which gets then caught by the LogAndContinueErrorHandler (see this thread: [Backend "Process moved to a different machine" and fails withh error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24855488/backend-process-moved-to-a-different-machine-and-fails-withh-error-500)).

After around 14 seconds and another 10 similar Errors, the "Process moved to a different machine.". I suggest the reason is that appengine recognizes the errors and assumes that something is wrong with the instance and shuts it down after a while.

As suggested in the other thread, i could ensure, that the move to a different machine keeps the process going, but since it really has an Error because something is too big / to long i better should work on the error.

Here is the error at the beginning of the error cascade, at the end the error stops on `com.googlecode.objectify.cache.MemcacheServiceRetryProxy invoke: Error performing memcache operation, retrying: public abstract void`

```
    15:49:18.779
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.LogAndContinueErrorHandler handleServiceError: Service error in memcache
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache getAll: exception getting multiple keys
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.handleApiProxyException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.absorbParentException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:109)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.handleParentException(FutureWrapper.java:51)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.getAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:64)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.KeyMemcacheService.getAll(KeyMemcacheService.java:75)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.cacheGetAll(EntityMemcache.java:346)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.putAll(EntityMemcache.java:285)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService$3.success(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:280)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService$3.success(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:269)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerSuccessFuture.trigger(TriggerSuccessFuture.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.isDone(TriggerFuture.java:89)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.get(TriggerFuture.java:104)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:34)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$2.now(Round.java:135)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$2.now(Round.java:132)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:172)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:164)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:73)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
    at ch.eaternity.server.DAO.loadEntityNow(DAO.java:383)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ProductServiceImpl.getProduct(ProductServiceImpl.java:21)
    at ch.eaternity.server.CompositeRoot.restoreJavaObject(CompositeRoot.java:237)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:137)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.invokeLifecycleCallbacks(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:167)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.access$000(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:24)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata$1.run(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.LoadContext.done(LoadContext.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.postExecuteHook(LoadEngine.java:191)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:33)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:73)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultNowFunction.apply(ResultNowFunction.java:20)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultNowFunction.apply(ResultNowFunction.java:9)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Chunk.next(Chunk.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Chunk.next(Chunk.java:10)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.next(Iterators.java:553)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$PeekingImpl.peek(Iterators.java:1162)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ChunkingIterator.hasNext(ChunkingIterator.java:52)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:356)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:147)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:129)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:11)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy.invoke(ResultProxy.java:32)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:530)
    at ch.eaternity.server.DAO.loadCompositeRootsByDateAndKitchenId(DAO.java:1058)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ReportServiceImpl.loadCompositeRoots(ReportServiceImpl.java:75)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ReportServiceImpl.loadSupplies(ReportServiceImpl.java:24)
    at ch.eaternity.server.reports.GeneralKitchenDataAnalyzer.generateAndSaveConcreteGeneralKitchenData(GeneralKitchenDataAnalyzer.java:45)
    at ch.eaternity.server.servlets.ReportGeneratingServlet.kickOffReportDataGeneration(ReportGeneratingServlet.java:75)
    at ch.eaternity.server.servlets.ReportGeneratingServlet.doPost(ReportGeneratingServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at ch.eaternity.server.NamespaceFilter.doFilter(NamespaceFilter.java:36)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
<continued in next message>
   
E
 15:49:18.779
<continued from previous message>
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:480)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
   
I
 15:49:20.272
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler handleApiProxyException: Memcache putAll: Unknown exception setting 0 keys: 
   
W
 15:49:20.276
com.googlecode.objectify.cache.MemcacheServiceRetryProxy invoke: Error performing memcache operation, retrying: public abstract void com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService.putAll(java.util.Map)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-fdcbff8350bb99f7(Request.java)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.MemcacheServiceRetryProxy.invoke(MemcacheServiceRetryProxy.java:68)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.putAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.KeyMemcacheService.putAll(KeyMemcacheService.java:80)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.empty(EntityMemcache.java:312)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.putAll(EntityMemcache.java:296)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService$3.success(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:280)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService$3.success(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:269)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerSuccessFuture.trigger(TriggerSuccessFuture.java:38)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.isDone(TriggerFuture.java:89)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.TriggerFuture.get(TriggerFuture.java:104)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ResultAdapter.now(ResultAdapter.java:34)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$2.now(Round.java:135)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$2.now(Round.java:132)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:172)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:164)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:73)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.LoadResult.now(LoadResult.java:25)
    at ch.eaternity.server.DAO.loadEntityNow(DAO.java:383)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ProductServiceImpl.getProduct(ProductServiceImpl.java:21)
    at ch.eaternity.server.CompositeRoot.restoreJavaObject(CompositeRoot.java:237)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor10.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.invokeLifecycleCallbacks(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:167)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.access$000(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:24)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata$1.run(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:127)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.LoadContext.done(LoadContext.java:70)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.LoadEngine$1.postExecuteHook(LoadEngine.java:191)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:33)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Round$1.nowUncached(Round.java:73)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultNowFunction.apply(ResultNowFunction.java:20)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultNowFunction.apply(ResultNowFunction.java:9)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Chunk.next(Chunk.java:27)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Chunk.next(Chunk.java:10)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.next(Iterators.java:553)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$PeekingImpl.peek(Iterators.java:1162)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ChunkingIterator.hasNext(ChunkingIterator.java:52)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:356)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:147)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:129)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.MakeListResult.translate(MakeListResult.java:11)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator.nowUncached(ResultTranslator.java:21)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy.invoke(ResultProxy.java:32)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:530)
    at ch.eaternity.server.DAO.loadCompositeRootsByDateAndKitchenId(DAO.java:1058)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ReportServiceImpl.loadCompositeRoots(ReportServiceImpl.java:75)
    at ch.eaternity.server.services.ReportServiceImpl.loadSupplies(ReportServiceImpl.java:24)
    at ch.eaternity.server.reports.GeneralKitchenDataAnalyzer.generateAndSaveConcreteGeneralKitchenData(GeneralKitchenDataAnalyzer.java:45)
    at ch.eaternity.server.servlets.ReportGeneratingServlet.kickOffReportDataGeneration(ReportGeneratingServlet.java:75)
    at ch.eaternity.server.servlets.ReportGeneratingServlet.doPost(ReportGeneratingServlet.java:46)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at ch.eaternity.server.NamespaceFilter.doFilter(NamespaceFilter.java:36)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache putAll: Unknown exception setting 0 keys
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$RpcResponseHandler.handleApiProxyException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:68)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl$RpcResponseHandlerForPut.handleApiProxyException(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:348)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper$1.absorbParentException(MemcacheServiceApiHelper.java:109)
<continued in next message>
   
W
 15:49:20.276
<continued from previous message>
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.handleParentException(FutureWrapper.java:51)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:90)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.quietGet(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.putAll(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:115)
    ... 91 more
```

Im not sure weather its related to appengine or objectify, see this thread for comparison:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/objectify-appengine/GzFmrQNMaI0/1ALIKbEY9agJ

Objectify: 4.0RC2
Appengine: 1.9.9

**Update 1**
After upgrading to Objectify 4.1.3., no exceptions occur anymore, but at the exactly same point in the iteration the `Process moved to a different machine.` warning occurs. Why is it moved then to a different machine?

**Update 2**
In the meantime, i reached couple of times the Memory limit and finally rised the backen instance to B4 which solved the problem for the moment.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Now the error moved a little bit, now i only get this exception around 100 times, until the process gets moved to a different machine.

```
com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceException: Memcache getAll: exception getting multiple keys
```

**Update 3**
Sometimes the batch process also runs through successfully! I dont understand... I'll try to figure out when its not successfull.

Anyone knowing where the problem could origin from? How to solve it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Until now i couldnt figure out what the problem is, it only happens occasionally. Ill post an Answer when i was able to solve it!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I can shed some light on Objectify's (and GAE's) behavior WRT memcache.

Objectify uses memcache as a read-through cache, so "memcache unavailable" is for all practical purposes the same as "empty result" - Objectify goes and gets the data out of the datastore. GAE's memcache API has a `LogAndContinueErrorHandler` for exactly this purpose - memecache errors are logged but otherwise ignored.

Unfortunately Google's `LogAndContinueErrorHandler` had a bug in that some types of memcache errors were neither logged nor ignored. Objectify got some new behavior (the aptly-named `MemcacheServiceRetryProxy`) which retries memcache API calls a few times and then gives up, returning an empty result. This what you are seeing with 4.0RC2.

Some time later Google fixed the handler not by changing the behavior of `LogAndContinueErrorHandler` (it was considered likely that some users were relying on exact behavior) but by deprecating that class and adding a `ConsistentLogAndContinueErrorHandler` which behaves... more consistently. A later version of Objectify switched to use this facility, and now you're seeing that behavior with 4.1.3 - less noisy.

So that's part of the story. Another part of the story is that at some point Objectify was just a little too smugly clever about optimizing calls to memcache, and sometimes would optimize a memcache call down to a zero-length list of keys. The memcache API doesn't like that, which is what *might* be responsible for `Memcache putAll: Unknown exception setting 0 keys`. More recent versions of Objectify skip the memcache call if there are no operations.

As for `Process moved to a different machine.`, I have no idea. It might be related, it might not.

Comment: Thnx for your insights, thats a good explanation i didnt find so far on the net! I added some updates. I probably try to upgrade to the newest objectify, but this involes quite a bit of work...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the process moving up on different instance, you can't control it anyhow.A machine may go down anytime and app engine will shift your process to another machine.You task should better be idempotent.